# Can we infinitely charge a hollow metal sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors, dielectric

I know this isnt practically possible due to dielectric breakdown of the surrounding medium but otherwise ...what would be the outcome?

Following is the link of the question which came up for me in a test....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWir.jpg

Based on the concept i want to know whether the "statement 1:" is true independently...

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by "otherwise"? What "concept" are you asking about?

Comment: usually in space there is a certain limit to which a conductor can be charged....... I was asking whether or not can we create such a system with infinite charge without dielectric breakdown

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Im Sorry as i was not familiar... I will wathout next time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum positive electric charge of solid body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34473) or [What limits the maximum sustainable surface charge density of a sphere in space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62416) or [What is the maximum surface charge density of aluminum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34063)

Comment: Maximum  possible charge of a body.....Mr Vladmir Kalitvianski has given an explanation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we cannot. Even in vacuum the electron repulsion energy may exceed the binding energy to the metallic core, so the extra electrons will leave the surface.

Also it is possible (theoretically) for a strong electric field to create electron-positron pairs that will weaken the field with time.